# how to load a file from the bundle in eclispe rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am loading a property file in the eclipse bundle but my code is using `InternalPlatform` from eclipse package which is not the best way to do that because it is restricted package from the eclipse  . How do I load this file from the classpath.

```
public Properties getProperties(String resourceName){
            Bundle bundle = InternalPlatform.getDefault().getBundle("sample-bundle");
            try {
                return PropertyFactory.getProperties(new URL("platform:/plugin/" + bundle.getSymbolicName() + "/" + resourceName));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Unable to load aegis config {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }



private static Properties getProperties(URL url) throws IOException {   
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    logger.info("Loading Properties  from {}", url);
    properties.load(url.openStream());
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to load a resource from a different bundle than the one containing this code?

Answer (score 1):

The `Platform` class provides an official way to get the bundle for a plugin given its id:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("sample-bundle");
```

You can then use the `FileLocator` class to find a resource in the bundle:

```
IPath path = new Path("relative path of resource in bundle");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
```

Note: `Platform` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin. `Path` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path`.

Comment: thanks is `Platform` class is java class or eclipse RCP class

Comment: Updated answer with exact packages for Platform (and Path). These are both core Eclipse classes in `org.eclipse.core.runtime`.